# Value Converter is executed before the data is updated in View Model property in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a very basic need, but it seems quite challenging to achieve such a simple thing in Xamarin Forms, especially when I compare it with the way the React Native let us do the same thing.

Anyways, so I am trying to highlight a frame's background color based on the selected Id. For that, I have created a value converter, and passing Id to check and convert to the desired background color.

**Below is my XAML Code:**

```
<Frame CornerRadius="6" Padding="10" Margin="5" WidthRequest="110" HeightRequest="80"
       BackgroundColor="{Binding TitleId, Converter={StaticResource 
       selectedGuidelineToColorConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Reference Guidelines}}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#x000f0806;" FontSize="20"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="13" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#333d47"/>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectedGuidelineCommand, Source={x:Reference Guidelines}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

**Below is my Converter Code:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var page = parameter as ContentPage;

    GuidelinesViewModel model = null;

    if(page != null)
    {
        model = page.BindingContext as GuidelinesViewModel;
    }

    if(model != null && model.CurrentVisibleGuideline != null && model.CurrentVisibleGuideline.TitleId == (int)value)
    {
        return "#808080";
    }

    return "#fff";
}
```

**My Model Code:**

```
public class Guideline
{
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    public List<QnA> QnA { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my View Model Code:**

```
Guideline guideline = null;
public Guideline CurrentVisibleGuideline
{
    get { return guideline; }
    set { SetProperty(ref guideline, value); }
}

public ICommand SelectedGuidelineCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Guideline>((guideline) => ExecuteSelectedGuidelineCommand(guideline));
    }
}

void ExecuteSelectedGuidelineCommand(Guideline guideline)
{
    CurrentVisibleGuideline = guideline;
}

async void GetGuidelines()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    Guidelines = new ObservableCollection<Guideline>();

    try
    {
        var guidelines = await DataStore.GetGuidelinesAsync(CurrentVisibleSection);

        foreach (var guideline in guidelines)
        {
            Guidelines.Add(guideline);
        }

        CurrentVisibleGuideline = Guidelines[0];
        TotalGuidelines = Guidelines.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

`"CurrentVisibleGuideline"` is a property in my View Model which contains the TitleId and other details of the selected guideline.

Problem is that, the converter code is executed before the `CurrentVisibleGuideline = Guidelines[0]` in the view model, and therefore, I get null in CurrentVisibleGuideline in the converter.

I believe that once the data is updated in the view model upon command execution, the XAML code should re-render the view and re-run the converter, but in my case it doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: Is your Frame Xaml with in a ListView?

Comment: Frame is inside the StackLayout, bound with the Guidelines item source. Based on the number of guidelines available, those many number of frames will be rendered in a scroll view. And the one selected, should get highlighted.

Comment: What is the `Guideline`  in your sample ? Please post the full code  . Or you can share the sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT: Thanks, the ```Guideline``` is an object with few properties. I have updated the code to show the definition of it.

Comment: When the page has finished loading, Is `Guidelines` populated and does your UI show the `Guideines` in the `StackLayout`?

Comment: First problem I see with this is the `BackgroundColor` is bound to `TitleId` but `TitleId` does not  fire the PropertyChanged event, so if the `TitleId` changes after the page has loaded the UI is not going to be updated.  The second problem is you're setting `CurrentVisibleGuideline` but this in itself doesn't update the `TitleId` on any of the `Guidelines` so again the UI will not be notified to update the `BackgroundColor`.  It would be better to bind on `CurrentVisibleGuideline` instead and pass the `TitleId` as a parameter to the converter.

Comment: It would be better to share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add an `IsSelected` boolean to you Guideline View Model.
- Update the convertor to take in a bool and return a string that will return
  your Hex color value.
- When you change the `CurrentVisibleGuideline` Set the IsSelected flag on your Guideline View Model.

ViewModel

```
public class Guideline
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }

    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    public List<QnA> QnA { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Guideline> Guidelines { get; set; }

Guideline guideline = null;
public Guideline CurrentVisibleGuideline
{
    get { return guideline; }
    set { SetProperty(ref guideline, value); }
}

public ICommand SelectedGuidelineCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Guideline>((guideline) => ExecuteSelectedGuidelineCommand(guideline));
    }
}

void ExecuteSelectedGuidelineCommand(Guideline guideline)
{
    CurrentVisibleGuideline = guideline;
}

async void GetGuidelines()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    Guidelines = new ObservableCollection<Guideline>();

    try
    {
        var guidelines = await DataStore.GetGuidelinesAsync(CurrentVisibleSection);

        foreach (var guideline in guidelines)
        {
            Guidelines.Add(guideline);
        }

        CurrentVisibleGuideline = Guidelines[0];
        TotalGuidelines = Guidelines.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}

void SetCurrentGuideline(Guideline guideline)
{
    CurrentVisibleGuideline = guideline;
    foreach (var gl in Guidelines)
        gl.IsSelected = gl.TitleId == CurrentVisibleGuideline.TitleId;
}
```

Converter

```
public class BooleanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string TrueValue { get; set; } = "#808080"
    public string FalseValue { get; set; } = "#FFF"

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return TrueValue;
            else
                return FalseValue;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Frame CornerRadius="6" Padding="10" Margin="5" WidthRequest="110" HeightRequest="80"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToString}}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#x000f0806;" FontSize="20"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="13" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#333d47"/>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectedGuidelineCommand, Source={x:Reference Guidelines}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

On a side note you will also need to turn the guideline(s) you get back from your DataStore into a ViewModel version.

Comment: Basically, there was a fundamental problem in the way I designed my view model. Thanks for your answer.